# Permission in web application - System.Management, Generic failure

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, dns, system.management

I want to access to System.Management and add dns record. Current code works fine on windows application, but I looking for a permission to run the code on web application too.

```
string site = "domain.com";
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
ManagementScope _scope  = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\Root\MicrosoftDNS", "host name"), co);
_scope.Connect();

ManagementObject mc = new ManagementClass(_scope, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_Zone"), null);
mc.Get();
ManagementBaseObject parameters = mc.GetMethodParameters("CreateZone");
parameters["ZoneName"] = site;
parameters["ZoneType"] = (UInt32)DNSServer.NewZoneType.Primary;
parameters["DsIntegrated"] = 0; //false
ManagementBaseObject createdEntry = mc.InvokeMethod("CreateZone", parameters, null);
```

I need the permission for web application, and here is what I did up to know:

**Windows Authentication:**

```
 <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
```

[image]

**Permission entire:**

[image]

**iis feature delegation:**

[image]

> **Update: you could to see the bug here on this [link](http://www.irantabliq.com/WebForm2.aspx)**

Comment: please make sure your WMI service is running (possibly it stopped/crashed/etc) when the "System.Management.ManagementException: Generic failure" happens.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks, current code works fine with windows application, I lost about 3 days for this bug. it's awful :(

Comment: Could you please share under which application pool identity your application is running?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal here I find what other people faced, same error without response :( https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3322cc53-259d-4c0d-9fbf-41dc51304988/trying-to-add-cname-to-dns-with-systemmanagement-results-in-generic-failure?forum=netfxnetcom